# How to put Query on the list with c# visual Studio?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

This is my Class (getProductItem) to get data from Query and set it on SAP Crystal Report :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class getProductItem
    {
        public static int nomor = 0;
        public int No
        {
            get
            {
                return getProductItem.nomor++; 
            }
        }
        public string nama_produk { get; set; }
        public string harga_satuan { get; set; }
        public string jumlah_penjualan { get; set; }
        public string total_harga { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And This is my issue, idk what i have to change with `.Query` , i ended up having error with this. `'MySqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no accesible edtension method 'Query'accepting a first argument of type 'MySqlConnection'could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

i'm following  a tutorial that using SQL database, but i'm using mysql database. So i don't know how to fix it.

Btw the code bellow is from another windows forms, that set a query to get data and put it on the list of `getProductItem` but it doesn't goes well

```
using (MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
{
  dbConn.Open();
  string insertQuery = "SELECT  p.nama_produk, d.harga_satuan, d.jumlah_penjualan, d.total_harga FROM detail_penjualan_produk d JOIN produk p ON p.id_produk = d.id_produk WHERE d.id_penjualan = '" + UCTransaction.IDPenjualan + "' ";
  List<getProductItem> list = dbConn.Query<getProductItem>(insertQuery, CommandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What error did you encounter?  Please provide some specific information.

Comment: i'm sorry, now you can see it above again, i just put it the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to install the Nuget package `Dapper` first, and add a using statement.

```
using ...
using Dapper;
using ...
```

Comment: you're right. it does fixed the problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @Ellie If this helps you, please click `√` to mark this as an answer.